# Why does HTML <a> tag sometimes work and other times doesn't in a 2 level nested accordion?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm using Bootstrap and I'm trying to make an accordion of items nested inside an accordion. So it would be like top level is an accordion containing many physical quantities panels, and each physical quantity panel's content is an accordion containing a list of SI-conversion-factors panels whose content is a list of units of measurements.

Every **a** tag on the top level accordion works but in the 2nd level accordion some **a** tags work and some don't.

**Download:**
You can see for your self by [downloading a zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/01sxm5uyexpd9z0/explaining%20a%20tag%20problem.zip?dl=0) containing minimum amount of code to replicate the problem:

```
minimal-code.html
collapse.js
jquery-2.2.4.min.js
css.css
```

**Pictures:**
I took some [pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODP6n.jpg) before and after clicking one that don't work and one that do work. Pictures are not from the minimal code to replicate problem version.

I like the accordion style to present the data, what would I have to do to make it work? If not, I can try other styles such as collapse or a simple nested list.

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset='utf-8'>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
              integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!-- <script src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="collapse.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"> -->
   </head>
   <body>
      <div aria-multiselectable="true" id="dimension-accordion" role="tablist" data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0">
         <div class="panel panel-info" data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79">
            <div role="tab" id="heading-dimension-id-79" class="panel-heading" data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.0">
               <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#dimension-accordion" href="#collapse-dimension-id-79" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-dimension-id-79" data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.0.0">
                  <h2 data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.0.0.0"><span class="badge" data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.0.0.0.0">31</span><span data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.0.0.0.1">current = {"A" 1}</span></h2>
               </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-dimension-id-79" aria-labelledby="heading-dimension-id-79" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse" data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1">
               <div id="accordion-conversion-factor-for-79" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0">
                  <div class="panel panel-default" data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$0=1999835">
                     <div role="tab" id="0.999835" class="panel-heading" data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$0=1999835.0">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-conversion-factor-for-79" href="#collapse-id-0.999835" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-id-0.999835" data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$0=1999835.0.0">
                           <h3 data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$0=1999835.0.0.0"><span class="badge" data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$0=1999835.0.0.0.0">4</span><span data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$0=1999835.0.0.0.1">0.999835</span></h3>
                        </a>
                     </div>
                     <div id="collapse-id-0.999835" aria-labelledby="0.999835" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse" data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$0=1999835.1">
                        <h4 data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$0=1999835.1.$4058">intamp</h4>
                        <h4 data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$0=1999835.1.$3015">intampere</h4>
                        <h4 data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$0=1999835.1.$4207">intamperes</h4>
                        <h4 data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$0=1999835.1.$4175">intamps</h4>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default" data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$1">
                     <div role="tab" id="1" class="panel-heading" data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$1.0">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-conversion-factor-for-79" href="#collapse-id-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-id-1" data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$1.0.0">
                           <h3 data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$1.0.0.0"><span class="badge" data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$1.0.0.0.0">7</span><span data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$1.0.0.0.1">1</span></h3>
                        </a>
                     </div>
                     <div id="collapse-id-1" aria-labelledby="1" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse" data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$1.1">
                        <h4 data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$1.1.$3269">A</h4>
                        <h4 data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$1.1.$2566">amp</h4>
                        <h4 data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$1.1.$1900">ampere</h4>
                        <h4 data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$1.1.$1857">amperes</h4>
                        <h4 data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$1.1.$303">amps</h4>
                        <h4 data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$1.1.$4186">galvat</h4>
                        <h4 data-reactid=".0.3.0.0.1.0.$79.1.0.$1.1.$604">galvats</h4>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.panel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.panel-info {
  border-color: #bce8f1;
}
.panel-info > .panel-heading {
  color: #31708f;
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  border-color: #bce8f1;
}
.panel-info > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
  border-top-color: #bce8f1;
}
.panel-info > .panel-heading .badge {
  color: #d9edf7;
  background-color: #31708f;
}
.panel-info > .panel-footer + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
  border-bottom-color: #bce8f1;
}

.panel-heading {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.badge {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 10px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #777;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.collapse {
  display: none;
}
.collapse.in {
  display: block;
}
```

**jquery-2.2.4.min.js:**

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js
```

**collapse.js:**

```
/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: collapse.js v3.3.6
 * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * ======================================================================== */


+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // COLLAPSE PUBLIC CLASS DEFINITION
  // ================================

  var Collapse = function (element, options) {
    this.$element      = $(element)
    this.options       = $.extend({}, Collapse.DEFAULTS, options)
    this.$trigger      = $('[data-toggle="collapse"][href="#' + element.id + '"],' +
                           '[data-toggle="collapse"][data-target="#' + element.id + '"]')
    this.transitioning = null

    if (this.options.parent) {
      this.$parent = this.getParent()
    } else {
      this.addAriaAndCollapsedClass(this.$element, this.$trigger)
    }

    if (this.options.toggle) this.toggle()
  }

  Collapse.VERSION  = '3.3.6'

  Collapse.TRANSITION_DURATION = 350

  Collapse.DEFAULTS = {
    toggle: true
  }

  Collapse.prototype.dimension = function () {
    var hasWidth = this.$element.hasClass('width')
    return hasWidth ? 'width' : 'height'
  }

  Collapse.prototype.show = function () {
    if (this.transitioning || this.$element.hasClass('in')) return

    var activesData
    var actives = this.$parent && this.$parent.children('.panel').children('.in, .collapsing')

    if (actives && actives.length) {
      activesData = actives.data('bs.collapse')
      if (activesData && activesData.transitioning) return
    }

    var startEvent = $.Event('show.bs.collapse')
    this.$element.trigger(startEvent)
    if (startEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    if (actives && actives.length) {
      Plugin.call(actives, 'hide')
      activesData || actives.data('bs.collapse', null)
    }

    var dimension = this.dimension()

    this.$element
      .removeClass('collapse')
      .addClass('collapsing')[dimension](0)
      .attr('aria-expanded', true)

    this.$trigger
      .removeClass('collapsed')
      .attr('aria-expanded', true)

    this.transitioning = 1

    var complete = function () {
      this.$element
        .removeClass('collapsing')
        .addClass('collapse in')[dimension]('')
      this.transitioning = 0
      this.$element
        .trigger('shown.bs.collapse')
    }

    if (!$.support.transition) return complete.call(this)

    var scrollSize = $.camelCase(['scroll', dimension].join('-'))

    this.$element
      .one('bsTransitionEnd', $.proxy(complete, this))
      .emulateTransitionEnd(Collapse.TRANSITION_DURATION)[dimension](this.$element[0][scrollSize])
  }

  Collapse.prototype.hide = function () {
    if (this.transitioning || !this.$element.hasClass('in')) return

    var startEvent = $.Event('hide.bs.collapse')
    this.$element.trigger(startEvent)
    if (startEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    var dimension = this.dimension()

    this.$element[dimension](this.$element[dimension]())[0].offsetHeight

    this.$element
      .addClass('collapsing')
      .removeClass('collapse in')
      .attr('aria-expanded', false)

    this.$trigger
      .addClass('collapsed')
      .attr('aria-expanded', false)

    this.transitioning = 1

    var complete = function () {
      this.transitioning = 0
      this.$element
        .removeClass('collapsing')
        .addClass('collapse')
        .trigger('hidden.bs.collapse')
    }

    if (!$.support.transition) return complete.call(this)

    this.$element
      [dimension](0)
      .one('bsTransitionEnd', $.proxy(complete, this))
      .emulateTransitionEnd(Collapse.TRANSITION_DURATION)
  }

  Collapse.prototype.toggle = function () {
    this[this.$element.hasClass('in') ? 'hide' : 'show']()
  }

  Collapse.prototype.getParent = function () {
    return $(this.options.parent)
      .find('[data-toggle="collapse"][data-parent="' + this.options.parent + '"]')
      .each($.proxy(function (i, element) {
        var $element = $(element)
        this.addAriaAndCollapsedClass(getTargetFromTrigger($element), $element)
      }, this))
      .end()
  }

  Collapse.prototype.addAriaAndCollapsedClass = function ($element, $trigger) {
    var isOpen = $element.hasClass('in')

    $element.attr('aria-expanded', isOpen)
    $trigger
      .toggleClass('collapsed', !isOpen)
      .attr('aria-expanded', isOpen)
  }

  function getTargetFromTrigger($trigger) {
    var href
    var target = $trigger.attr('data-target')
      || (href = $trigger.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '') // strip for ie7

    return $(target)
  }


  // COLLAPSE PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ==========================

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.collapse')
      var options = $.extend({}, Collapse.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)

      if (!data && options.toggle && /show|hide/.test(option)) options.toggle = false
      if (!data) $this.data('bs.collapse', (data = new Collapse(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    })
  }

  var old = $.fn.collapse

  $.fn.collapse             = Plugin
  $.fn.collapse.Constructor = Collapse


  // COLLAPSE NO CONFLICT
  // ====================

  $.fn.collapse.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.collapse = old
    return this
  }


  // COLLAPSE DATA-API
  // =================

  $(document).on('click.bs.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle="collapse"]', function (e) {
    var $this   = $(this)

    if (!$this.attr('data-target')) e.preventDefault()

    var $target = getTargetFromTrigger($this)
    var data    = $target.data('bs.collapse')
    var option  = data ? 'toggle' : $this.data()

    Plugin.call($target, option)
  })

}(jQuery);
```

Comment: No one is going to download your zip file to help you. Add a [mcve] in your question and see [ask]

Comment: Please put down your html code over here. After sometime the download-code link might not be available.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: @Smit done. I took out as much code as possible to focus on the problem. I checked to make sure problem still happens with this amount of code.

Comment: @j08691 Link was replaced with one to download the minimalized version. Just extract into some folder and open minimal-code.html. Link is there for whoever's lazy.

Comment: is this three links added to html head?  `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: @Smit No, just:
`<head>`
`   <meta charset="utf-8">`
`   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">`
`   <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>`
`   <script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com//ez22/1.js"></script>`
`</head>`

wow sorry for the formatting, comment section is different.

Comment: @Smit I don't ref the http links. I actually download the files into a folder and ref the files in the folder relative to the .html file

Comment: Could use links instead and see if that solves the issue?

Comment: @Smit used the http links, but problem still persist. I read both <a> tags and they both have the same structure yet one works and the other doesn't and I have no idea why. I have tried <button> and same result.

Comment: @Jjunior130 Could please update your code with the added-links(HTML-HEAD) for bootstraps? Because sometime the issue persists with in the links or the referenced css/js.

Comment: @Smit done. I commented out ref to local files and added ref to https links. It behaves more smoothly now, but problem still there.